# Interpret one Python function

Tags: python

Could you please help me to interpret the meaning of this function, and the way to use it? Thank you.

```
def isNaN(num):
    return num != num
```

Comment: See also `math.isnan()`.

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal *"it can logically only be NaN"* - Or anything else with the same behavior.

Comment: @MarkTolonen Thanks for your input. These two functions are not equivalent.

Comment: @Sophia I know they are not.  Your version can be fooled by a class with `def __eq__(self, other): return False`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [...Nan](https://www.codespeedy.com/check-if-a-given-string-is-nan-in-python/) stands for Not a Number. It is a member of the numeric data type
> that represents an unpredictable value. For example, Square root of a
> negative number is a NaN, Subtraction of an infinite number from
> another infinite number is also a NaN. so basically, NaN represents an
> undefined value in a computing system.

You could use it to check the results of calculations, to debug... basically anything you want to see if it cannot be resolved to a number.